# RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument when adding route when creating a macvlan on a different subnet

Tags: networking, docker, linux-networking, docker-networking

I am using a Synology NAS linked to my network via ip 192.168..13 on Eth1. Now I want to instate a Macvlan on it so I can provide my docker containers with their own ip and full range of ports.

My router provides a DHCP server and an ip range of 192.168.0.0/24. I figured I'd create the macvlan on the range 192.168.10.128/16 so it wouldn't clash.

The steps I performed; I've created a macvlan network in docker like so:

```
docker network create -d macvlan \
--subnet=192.168.10.0/24 \
--gateway=192.168.10.1 \
--ip-range=192.168.10.1/24 \
-o parent=eth1 macvlan_network
```

Then I wanted to add the network routing on the NAS itself, so I ran:

```
ip link add macvlan0 link eth1 type macvlan mode bridge
ip addr add 192.168.10.254/32 dev macvlan0
ip link set macvlan0 up
ip route add 192.168.10.1/16 dev macvlan0
```

However this last line generates an error and I don't understand what's going on...:

> RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument

```
ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:09:d0:0d:8e:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:09:d0:0d:8e:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eth1.10: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d6:01:12:61:47:ba brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:42:36:f2:a5:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: docker-f26db83e: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:42:43:b8:e5:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: docker5aebb14@if8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether a6:c6:a8:db:38:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
26: dockerd6b68f2@if25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker-f26db83e state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 3a:db:86:5d:cf:79 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
31: macvlan0@eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/ether 96:76:fd:12:ba:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

With my adapter's config being

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
DEVICE=eth1
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
IPV6INIT=auto_dhcp
IPV6_ACCEPT_RA=1
```

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how this network config should work, I'm not very experienced with it so could really use any advice where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `192.168.10.1/16` as the subnet you want to use for your MACVLAN and pass through your bridge? The `/16` of course translates to the entire `192.168.x.x` range, which suggests that you want to pass all traffic destined either for the macvlan or for the DHCP issued addresses through the bridge... I actually would have expected you to use `/24` there.

Comment: Apparently I wasn't thinking straight last night, that was indeed the answer and now it's all running like a charm. Thanks!!